# French accents in PHP (again)

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I've looked at all the relevant topics on the site and this particular gotcha does not seem to be covered

I exported a Word 2016 document (in French) as filtered HTML ( filtered= no office specific stuff included). If I show the file in my browser as html, everything is fine - all the accents show correctly. ( Charset is utf-8 and it's not coming from a database). But when I change the extension to .php and run it, all the french characters are shown as black diamonds with a question mark inside.

If I express the french characters as html entities, they show correctly, but I don't want to do this as the fix - there are hundreds of them in there, and I don't want to edit the text - it's not mine and the author would have to proof read it all again just to check the accents.

So I figured it's a PHP (5.5.26) issue - but I can't see anything in the ini file which might affect this - it looks like UTF-8 is the default charset if you don't change anything,

What's the fix ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem with just **one** file, you can use the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
?>
```

On the html part add or change:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 />
```

---

If you've **thousands** of files and you don't want to change them manually you can try to modify the following line on your `php.ini`:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

to

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1";
```

Save and **restart** the server.